# Connection String Confusion SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

I'm using the following string:

```
<add name="Default" 
     connectionString="Server=; Database=SMCSNPROD; User Idlil; Password=" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I checked the logs and found:

```
2018-03-12 23:12:20.37 spid7s      Server name is 'CORE'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
```

I confirmed that the following are true:

```
2018-03-12 23:12:20.46 Server      Server is listening on [ ::1 <ipv6> 1434].
2018-03-12 23:12:20.46 Server      Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 1434].
```

And I disabled Windows firewall. I've also allowed remote connections to this server.

Any suggestions?

Edit: I can also connect to it locally, server "CORE", using SQL authentication (in the connection string).

Comment: What is the actual error message? Are you connecting from the same machine or a different machine?

Comment: Please do not share connection strings on a public community. They could be taken and hacked.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Visual Studio, go to **Tools**..
2. There you can find **Connect To DataBase**..
3. You set Data Source as **MICROSOFT SQL SERVER**..
4. And click the arrow of server name and select   **Your Sever**...
5. Use **SQL Server authentication** and input your user name & password ...
6. If SQL Server authorization is not working, then you go for **Windows authentication**..
7. Choose the database you want and **don't press Ok**...
8. Go to **Advanced**; here you can see the bottom has some of **Integrated Security=True...** Use this in your `web.config`
9. Remove old....

Comment: You Must NOT Capitalize Each And Every Single Word In English!!

Comment: Okay  i will change that next time :)